# Como obtener lista de outputs de audio del sistema con la api de Java Sounds?

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a usar la api de java sounds y me encontre con un problema que no puedo resolver.Quiero obtener la lista de outputs del sistema y ponerlas en un combobox,pero no se como puedo elegir un objeto de tipo Line o Mixer con las caracteristicas que yo quiera porque al obtener la lista,te muestra todas las lineas y puertos del sistema.Aca dejo lo que intente que esta mal.

```
Info[] mixers=AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    for(Info i:mixers) {
    Mixer m=AudioSystem.getMixer(i);
    Line.Info linea= m.getLineInfo();
    if(linea!=null&&(AudioSystem.isLineSupported(Port.Info.LINE_OUT)&&AudioSystem.isLineSupported(linea))) {
    System.out.println("out");
    }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO:
Lo que hago es obtener todas las mezcladoras con sus respectivas informaciones**(Mixer.Info**) e itero sobre ellas para obtener con esta info sus objectos mezcladoras**(Mixer)**.Una vez obtenido el objeto mixer,obtengo todas sus lineas(SourceDataLine.Info)e  itero nuevamente sobre ellas.Si cada una de sus lineas no es nula y son de la clase **SourceDataLine**,entonces se añaden al ComboBox

**CODIGO:**

```
    Info[] mixers=AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
for(Info i:mixers) {
Mixer m=AudioSystem.getMixer(i);
Line.Info[] lineas= m.getSourceLineInfo();
for(Line.Info l:lineas) {
if(l!=null&&l.getLineClass().getName()==SourceDataLine.class.getName()) {
box.addItem(i.getName());}}
    
}
```